# Can a tracking script hurt your SEO?

Tags: seo, html, links

In this case the script that I'm talking about is as below. It contains a redirect that shows the original url, but actually is a cloaked URL that can be ignored by adding `data-pzz="false"`. So a SEO link will look like this:

```
<a href="http://advertiser.com" data-pzz="false" />
```

Can this hurt SEO/normal links?

Comment: So when `data-pzz="false"` it means that the link isn't sent through a click tracker?     I'm a bit confused by your explanation.

Comment: <a href="http://advertiser.com" data-pzz="false" />  is invalid HTML  "a" tags are not self closing

Answer (score 1):

data-pzz="false" looks like a [HTML5 data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).

As far as SEO impact goes, most tracking code would not impact anything unless the code slows down the page significantly. Just make sure that that is not the case.